# How to get project root directory inside cmake toolchain file, is it possible?

Tags: c++, cmake

I doing crossplatform building, and try to use cmake. So I create my-toolchain-file.cmake in which customize c++ linker command. Linking for my baremetal staff can be done like:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE
      "<CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER> <CMAKE_CXX_LINK_FLAGS> <LINK_FLAGS> <OBJECTS> <LINK_LIBRARIES> ${SDK_ROOT}/Libraries/${BUILD_TARGET}/${BUILD_TYPE}/memory.a -o <TARGET_BASE>"
      "if not exist <TARGET_BASE> ( mkdir <TARGET_BASE> )"
      "${SDK_ROOT}/Tools/CommandLineTools/Make/MakeBin.exe <TARGET_BASE> <TARGET_BASE>/main"
      "${SDK_ROOT}/Tools/CommandLineTools/Make/MakeManifest.exe --desc ${APP_DESC} --meta ${APP_META} -o <TARGET_BASE>/main.m"
      "copy ${SDK_ROOT_WIN}\\Libraries\\${BUILD_TARGET}\\${BUILD_TYPE}\\syslib.so <TARGET_BASE>\\rtld >NUL"
      "copy ${SDK_ROOT_WIN}\\Libraries\\${BUILD_TARGET}\\${BUILD_TYPE}\\Sdk.so <TARGET_BASE>\\sdk >NUL"
      "${SDK_ROOT}/Tools/SomeTool.exe createimage -o <TARGET_BASE> --desc ${APP_DESC} --meta ${APP_META} --type Exe --program <TARGET_BASE>bin"
      "rmdir /S /Q <TARGET_BASE>"
      "del /Q <TARGET_BASE>"
    )
```

Inside customized linker command I have to get path to manifest file which relative to project CMakeLists.txt not to toolchain file. How I can set my APP_META variable inside toolchain file? I try:

```
set(APP_META "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/Application.manifest")
```

It is not working (toolchain file and CMakeLists.txt in different places). How to get root directory path inside cmake toolchain file? Thanks in advance!

Comment: In all honesty, this type of thing belongs in the project CMakeLists.txt, not the toolchain description. There should be some way to determine the toolchain and add the manifest when necessary. This is just a dirty hack.

Comment: @rubenvb As you can see, my link command is composite from several sub commands. If I create some CUSTOM_MANIFEST var in CMakeLists.txt how I manage to update CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE?

Comment: This is just a plain [POST_BUILD command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_custom_command.html#build-events). This mechanism allows you to specify what the output is of the command such that dependency tracking isn't broken.

Comment: @rubenvb With POST_BUILD I have to add custom_target to every my project (to every CMakeLists.txt) and it all be the same. So I decide to write once toolchain. May be I can do it in toolchain file?

Comment: you could also write a `function` or `macro` and stuff it in a `.cmake` file that you share across projects.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR works for me.

```
set(APP_META "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Application.manifest")
```